# Difference between the output of hostname.exe and $env:ComputerName?

Tags: windows, powershell, hostname

I'm experiencing differences between the value of `$env:ComputerName` and the output of the *hostname.exe* command in a script that checks a machine's hostname against a predefined set:

```
if ($env:ComputerName -in $hostnames) { ... }
```

However, it seems like I cannot rely on the value of `$env:ComputerName` because it sometimes differs from the hostname of a machine on the network:

```
PS> hostname 
Example

PS> $env:ComputerName 
EXAMPLE
```

Besides the casing, why would these provide different values? On one machine, the name is significantly different between the two—*hostname.exe* outputs the expected name while `$env:ComputerName` contains an incorrect name. Does PowerShell retrieve the value from a different source than *hostname.exe*?

Comment: This is not related to Powershell. Try `cmd` and type `hostname`  and `set Comp`

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/887173/what-is-a-hostname-versus-a-computer-name-versus-a-subdomain-versus-www

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas. Not quite a dupe, but I'll close the question. Do I understand correctly, then, that *hostname.exe* pulls from the DHCP-assigned hostname in this case?

Comment: as far as my understanding goes, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$env` namespace is populated by `PowerShell.exe` when it loads from the set of environment variables.  It pulls these from the process that started it or from the registry.  `$env:COMPUTERNAME` should match the `%COMPUTERNAME%` environment variable.  Notably, when the value of an environment variable changes, it does *not* update that value in all open processes.

I'm not 100% sure what `hostname.exe` pulls from, but I believe that it requires that TCP/IP be loaded on a system.  It may be querying the network name that the host network adapter is listening for, or may be querying the network configuration (via the registry or some other method).

The most common instance where the two values don't match is after a computer has been renamed but before it has been restarted to complete the name change.

Answer (score 2):

Hostname - Displays the host name portion of the full computer name of the computer. The computer hostname is usually (but not always) the same as the %COMPUTERNAME% variable (which the $env:ComputerName is using) https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490919.aspx

I suspect that at the very bottom they are both saved in the registry database, just different locations:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`
and
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName`

You can test this guess, but you will need to restart your machine.